# Как правильно прописать в скрипте событие для определённого контейнера?

Tags: javascript, события

Есть такое событие, для мобильного устройства:

```js
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
    $('body').removeClass('MyClass');
    $('body').addClass('NewClass');
});
```

Как правильно прописать, что бы срабатывало в определённом контейнере?

Пробовал так:

```js
$(document).delegate('.MyClass', 'touchmove', function (event) {
  // действие
});


$(document).on('.MyClass', 'touchmove', function (event) {
  // действие
});


$('.MyClass').addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
  // действие
});
```

но так не работает..

Comment: @Lukas так тоже не сработало (

Comment: @gargool, так должно сработать. `$(document).on('touchmove', '.MyClass', function (event) {
  // действие
});`. Под словом не работает, что вы имеете введу?

Comment: @Lukas, так точно не будет работать. Это суржик какой-то

Comment: Какие-то библиотеки можно использовать? Или нужно на чистом Java Script?

Comment: @YuriyProkopets использую jQuery

Comment: @Node_pro "Под словом не работает, что вы имеете введу?" - не происходит смена классов на body.

Comment: @Gargool, можете предоставить полностью код, может дело не в событие? Также вопрос как вы тестируете?

Comment: @Node_pro Тестирую: открываю на мобиле, чищу кэш, обновляю страницу. Действие нужно такое: $('body').removeClass('MyClass');
    $('body').addClass('NewClass');

Comment: @Node_pro, да спасибо. Это чет меня поплавило )

Comment: @Lukas, бывает ;-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сработал такой вариант:

```js
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function() {
  if( document.body.className.match('MyClass') ) {
    // действие
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

В эмуляторе работают оба варианта. Возможно вы в обработчике используете `event.stopPropagation()` и поэтому не работает?

```js
$('#body').delegate('.MyClass', 'touchmove', function (event) {
  console.log('delegate');
});


$('#body').on('touchmove', '.MyClass', function (event) {
  console.log('on');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body">
  <div class="MyClass">12345</div>
</div>
```

Comment: в эмуляторе всё работает, а на мобиле нет.